# spark LOCAL and alluxio client

Tags: apache-spark, classpath, local, alluxio

I'm running spark in LOCAL mode and trying to get it to talk to alluxio.  I'm getting the error:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class alluxio.hadoop.FileSystem not found

I have looked at the page here:
https://www.alluxio.org/docs/master/en/Debugging-Guide.html#q-why-do-i-see-exceptions-like-javalangruntimeexception-javalangclassnotfoundexception-class-alluxiohadoopfilesystem-not-found

Which details the steps to take in this situation, but I'm not finding success.

According to Spark documentation, I can instance a local Spark like so:

```
SparkSession.builder
  .appName("App")
  .getOrCreate
```

Then I can add the alluxio client library like so:

```
sparkSession.conf.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", ALLUXIO_SPARK_CLIENT)
sparkSession.conf.set("spark.executor.extraClassPath", ALLUXIO_SPARK_CLIENT)
```

I have verified that the proper jar file exists in the right location on my local machine with:

```
logger.error(sparkSession.conf.get("spark.driver.extraClassPath"))
logger.error(sparkSession.conf.get("spark.executor.extraClassPath"))
```

But I still get the error.  Is there anything else I can do to figure out why Spark is not picking the library up?

Please note I am not using spark-submit - I am aware of the methods for adding the client jar to a spark-submit job.  My Spark instance is being created as local within my application and this is the use case I want to solve.

As an FYI there is another application in the cluster which is connecting to my alluxio using the fs client and that all works fine.  In that case, though, the fs client is being packaged as part of the application through standard sbt dependencies.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the hopes that this helps someone else:

My problem here was not that the library wasn't getting loaded or wasn't on the classpath, it was that I was using the "fs" version of the client rather than the "hdfs" version.

I had been using a generic 1.4 client - at some point this client was split into a fs version and an hdfs version.  When I updated this for 1.7 recently I mistakenly added the "fs" version.